# Motorola Atrix 4g reboots itself

Tags: motorola-atrix-4g

I've just got a new Motorola Atrix 4g and have experience random reboots of the phone, this generally happens when it is in my pocket or otherwise unattended.
Usually during the work day when browsing, playing games, listening to music or using the GPS it behaves itself.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Mine is doing this too. Did you get yours replaced?

Comment: Yes, I contacted my network provider (Orange UK) and they send me out a new handset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a hardware issue.  I suggest promptly replacing it with your carrier before your return grace period is up (30 days with AT&T, for example.)  You will need to do this at the same store where you purchased the handset.

I have the exact same problem with my new Atrix.  Unfortunately (for me) I unlocked its bootloader, so AT&T is refusing to honor the warranty.  I sent it in to Motorola for repairs, but it's still doing the same thing (Moto was nice enough to re-lock the bootloader, but AT&T is still not budging.)  In my case, I have a feeling that it's either damaged battery contacts on the phone, or perhaps a faulty battery itself.  I am planning to send it to Motorola again (on their dime this time) to see if they can fix it for real this time.

Comment: Nice to know AT&T is definitely not going to honor warranty on unlocked phones.

Comment: I guess it depends on the in-store clerks (some are more sympathetic than others,) but AT&T's official corporate policy is "F.U." when it comes to unlocked bootloaders.

Comment: Started to get a dead spot on the camera sensor as well, so it is being replaced by my carrier tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I've been noticing this too - it seems to only happen when I'm enabling > 2G data access.

I've managed to cut down the amount of reboots by installing Cyanogenmod 7 and a custom kernel, which I found here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1156040

It's down to 1 or 2 reboots a week now, which is manageable.

Comment: Since I've had a replacement handset I only had around 1-2 reboots every couple of months, usually when downloading and installing apps.